# Как показать n-ое количество View?

Tags: android

Пусть у меня есть некоторое число `n`, которая может изменятся. Она может лежать в интервале от 1 до 15,например. Проблема состоит в том что нужно расположить `n` `TextView`(или `Button`) . То есть количество элементов не фиксирована,это и является проблемой. Если вы все еще не поняли проблему, вспомните приложение `4 pics one word`, где для некого ответа,длина которого `n` , появляются `n` неких view-шек(места куда будут поставлены буквы ответа) .

Мой подход,который вряд-ли верен: 
Создать программно некий View/Layout, куда будут добавляться TextView/Button-ы в n - ом количестве. Но я не знаю правильно ли это решение.

Прошу вас подсказать мне,с какой стороны подойти к проблеме и какую концепцию следует использовать чтобы решить проблему?

Comment: Используйте [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: Не думаю что ListView подходит для этой ситуации.

Comment: Попробуйте вот это: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: @andy11 почему? у вас разные veiw?

Comment: @Соколов Спасибо за ответ. У меня одинаковые view. Вы использовали `4 pics 1 word` ? Там нет `ListView`. Сейчас программно создаю view, и добавляю их в `LinearLayout` в n-ом количестве. Если горизонтально не будет вмещаться,перейду на следующую строку. Но пока не придумал как это хэндлить. Если не получится буду использовать flexboxLayout.

Comment: @andy11 Проблема, значит в переходе на следующую строку?

Comment: А можно вообще обойтись без view-шек, все нарисовать в канвасе)

Comment: @Соколов Да,потому что если у меня слово из 9 букв, то мне надо решать как их расположить. В 2 строки , где в первой строке 4 буквы , а в следующей 5. Каждую деталь нужно хэндлить